# Disable CSV imports in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I have a supervisor who has a very annoying habit of editing our MySQL database in MS Excel. He does this by exporting the tables as a CSV, opening them in Excel, editing them, saving as a CSV, and re-importing. But there are some incompatibilities between PHPMyAdmin/MySQL and Excel, and so far this has led to two major system crashes (once because he tried to import an entire database from a CSV, which obviously makes no sense since CSVs don't delineate tables; and once because Excel added two extra rows to the CSV with incompatible data).

Since he refuses to listen when I tell him  to stop doing this, I'd like to disable CSV import on his copy of PHPMyAdmin. We still need to be able to import SQL files, though. Is there any way to specifically disable imports of CSV files? In the PHPMyAdmin settings, I see that you can set default values, but how can I just disable that format altogether?

Answer (score 0):

Go into the PHPMyAdmin source code and comment out the body of the function that handles CSV? It looks like commenting out line 121 of [config.values.php](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csv) will sort you. Let me know if you need further assistance.